# Option for pgfplots externalization with "list and make" to display full error

Tags: tikz-external

I have been using LuaLatex with the externalization library with these options in my preamble

```
   \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
   \tikzsetexternalprefix{figurescache/}
   \tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
```

After I compile my main latex document, I have to perform a "make" on the main file in order for the `pgfplots`/`tikz` figures to be generated. This step is fine. However, when there is an error in my `tikz` code, I am not able to see a detailed error message. I want to be able to see something similar to

```
"line 110, undefined control sequence"
```

in the command prompt. Is there an option for it?

As requested, a MWE would be something similar to

```
  \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
  \tikzsetexternalprefix{figurescache/}
  \tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
   \begin{document}
    Random Text here.
    \begin{figure}
    \centering{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5, axis lines=none]
    \addplot[only marks, mark size=2pt] table[x=xs, y=ys]{
        xs  ys
         1     1
         1     2
         1     3
    };
    \draw (axis cs: 2, 1) node[left]{{\footnotesize $i-1$}};
    \draw (axis cs: 2, 2) node[left]{{\footnotesize$i$}};
    \draw (axis cs: 2, 3) node[left]{{\footnotesize$i+1$}};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
     }
    \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

After compiling the above code, one would have to create the figure using the `make` command from the terminal. Now, if there happens to be a typo in the block containing the `tikzpicture`, the make command will just abort and no meaningful error will show in the terminal. If you remove

```
       \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
       \tikzsetexternalprefix{figurescache/}
       \tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
```

and perform a simple compilation, if there is an error,  a more meaningful error message will show. What I want is to be able to see meaningful errors while performing the `make` command. 
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer to my own question. What I needed to do was to disable the interaction mode. This can be done by adding the following options in the preamble:

```
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -halt-on-error -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

With that option, I am now able to read the error regarding the pgfplots in the command line.